# Can't get the PreferenceFragment to work (Compiling error)

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-preferences

[image]

I am getting error when i try to compile my project: "The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragmentPreferences)". As far as i know, the PreferenceFragment is a Fragment? I am developing for android 4.0 but i have to use android-support-v4 library because my project incluedes also ViewPager. I found this example at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment:

```
// Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
```

But i can't get it to work.

My code:

```
case R.id.menu_settings:
    FragmentPreferences prefs = new FragmentPreferences();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, prefs);
    ft.commit();
    break;
```

FragmentPreferences:

```
public class FragmentPreferences extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because `PreferenceFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment`, rather than the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` that the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` is expecting.

As of yet, there is no official backport of the `PreferenceFragment` to the support library. However, you can use libraries such as [UnifiedPreferences](https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference) to fill this gap.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `import` statements at the top of your code. Likely one of the classes you are using is from `support` while the other is not.

Comment: If i change any of those classes it will break my viewpager.

Comment: As ianhanniballake suggested above, you will have to seek alternatives. I would just resort to using a `PreferenceActivity` in the meantime if you don't really need fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unofficial backport of the PreferenceFragment to the support library. Last update was Feb 2015 & it's compatible with lollipop devices. [android-support-v4-preferencefragment](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment)

```
import android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment;
```

Comment: care to explain why it's a bad solution?

Comment: The solution that I have searched for a long time.

Comment: By the way,  
**UnifiedPreferences** has got lots of issues, like fragment not calling and styleable conflict with shecrlock actionbar library... etc... & I **hate** **UnifiedPreferences** library which cost me 2 hours almost.  
But this Compat library is awesome and solved my problem in a minute :) Thanks @TanJitRen