# how to show setting with preferenceFragment in DrawerLayout in android?

Tags: android, drawerlayout, setting, preferencefragment

I use `DrawerLayout` including 4 pages. I want to create `setting` page for my app. 
This is MainActivity.class for initializing `DrawerLayout`:

```
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_item_home:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_item_setting:
            fragmentClass = SettingFragment.class;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_item_help:
            fragmentClass = HelpFragment.class;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_item_about:
            fragmentClass =AboutFragment.class;
            break;

        default:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
            break;
    } try {
        fragment = (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is SettingFragment.class:

```
   import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

public SettingFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_settings);

}
```

}

But as i run and click on setting in drawer layout , nothing shows in setting page.

ence

So, how can I solve it?

Comment: I notice you are using support.v4 Fragment, and you can't mix PreferenceFragment - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078029/cant-get-the-preferencefragment-to-work-compiling-error